# PANEL structure within HPL (high performance Linpack) code

Tags: c, hpc, scientific-computing

Recently, I am delving into HPL code and try to understand the underlying implementation mechanism of HPL. (http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/)

Right now, I am a little confused with some parameters in HPL_T_panel structure. (include/hpl_panel.h).

```
A;                  /* ptr to trailing part of A */
* WORK;                              /* work space */
* L2;                                /* ptr to L */
* L1;                /* ptr to jb x jb upper block of A */ 
lda;                 /* local leading dim of array A */ 
ldl2;                /* local leading dim of array L2 */
```

A couple of questions:

1. What's the meaning of 'lda' and 'ldl2'?  What's the difference between leading dimension and number of rows of L2?
2. What's the value of A, L1 and L2?  In other words, what's the exact size of L, U and sub-matrix after each iteration of panel factorization?  I tried to keep track of these values during iterations but cannot tell the pattern.

For instance, suppose the following parameters for HPL:

```
N   1024  (matrix size)
NB 128    (block size)
PxQ 2x2   (process grid)
```

For the 'Loop over the columns of A' with (src/pgesv/HPL_pdgesv0.c), what's the values of A, L1, L2 for each iteration on each process?  Could you give me some statistic analysis here?  Such as index and remaining matrix size.

I'd appreciate it if someone (who are familiar with HPL source code) give me some suggestion.